# displaying RDF model in jsp

Tags: jsp, rdf

i'm currently writing a program that takes user input from a form and enters it into an RDF model  and displays the model on a JSP page .So far i have the form and the RDF model but I have been unable to display the RDF model.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider why you're trying to show the user the model and what you expect them to do with it.  I think for the most part showing a user a blob of triples, especially if they are not familiar with RDF, is hostile.  That's machine readable information.

If you just want to tell the user, this is the information you entered, then something like [RDFa](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/) might be relevant.  People are going to be able to digest a normal web page far easier than serialized RDF.  Or perhaps you can output the results in some sort of graphical format, maybe using a [library](http://thejit.org/) to show the the RDF graph.  The graph can be interesting at times, there are some interesting visualizations you can probably come up with, but it is not neccessarily an approach that will scale with large graphs, and it's still harder for a person to consume than just showing them a normal web page.

If you're just doing this for debugging, write the model into a String and print the string into the JSP.  Otherwise, keep the RDF details to yourself and show the user a normal page, that's my suggestion.  Just because you're using RDF under the hood does not mean you should be foisting that on the user.  You don't see people build a Rails app where all the display for the user is in Ruby code.  No, they show them HTML.

Comment: Hi would still like some help with this question if possible .I am trying to generate and Display FOAF profiles

Comment: Showing a user RDF is generally pretty hostile and there is no reason for you to do that unless you have the specific requirement that RDF must be displayed as-is.  If that's the case, just write the RDF out in Turtle syntax and be done with it.  But if you want something useable, create a normal webpage that displays the information as if there was no RDF, that's quite simple and the best route for your users.  If you want them to be able to access the RDF, either embed it with RDFa, include a link in the header to the RDF, or open up a SPARQL endpoint.